# Reports folder issue

Tags: reporting, sharing

I got a problem fpr which I am unable to figure out the solution.

I was asked by a person that if a particular reports folder is restricted to only individuals that he asks to assign?

If thats the case, he wants me to add a person.

And also he wants me to see if few other people were already added or not

I couldnt find to whom that report was shared with and also coudnt assign a new person

I am new to admin role so your help would be greatly appreciated. If you need anymore details regarding the above question please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Reports" tab and mouse over the report folder in question. A menu button will appear to the right (displaying a pin icon); select the "Share" item in that menu and a dialog will appear where you can share the folder with users or groups or roles etc.